# iis not displaying the website after aspnet_regiis

Tags: iis-7.5

internet explorer *cannot find the web page error* message after the following command

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

and I have reset the iis also but it is displaying as `Internet Explorer cannot found the page`

Answer (score 0):

```
   1) %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

   2) %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

I have executed both and after that it got worked.
but my machine is 64 bit so i have used 1st commandand then i tried 2nd command then it worked